# jquery maxlength "æ" or "ø" or "å" should count as two characters

Tags: jquery, character, validation, maxlength

I want to send text through a sms gateway, and they have a limit of 11 characters, in the from field. and æ or ø or å count as two characters. 
I use jquery validator, to count, and show user message, how do I get maxlength, to minus two every time, the users enter æ or ø or å, and only minus one character, when it's from a-z ??

Right now the script, allow a-z and æøå, 0-9 and space, but it don't count æøå as two characters. how do I do that?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
return value.match(new RegExp("^" + param + "$"));
});
from: {
            required: false,
            accept: "[a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ ]+",
            minlength: 2,    
            maxlength: 11
},
```

Comment: Is it irrelevant what happens to all other characters?

Comment: Hi jukka, I thought of having a-zA-Z0-9æøåÆØÅ and space to be allowed, all other characters should be denied, and æøå should count as two characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function countChar(mystring){
    var count=0;
    for (var i=0;i<mystring.length;i++)
    {
        if (mystring[i].match(/[æøåÆØÅ]/))
            count += 2;
        else
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hi tony, that look like php, or is it jquery?, I ask because, I need a live validation, where the user don't have to post, there form to get feedback ??

Comment: @user3291960 that's pure Javascript. I think you are looking for something like this:
`function validate(mystring)  
{  
     var count=0;  
     for (var i in mystring)  
     {  
         if (mystring[i].match(/[æøåÆØÅ]/))  
             count +=2;  
         else if (mystring[i].match(/[a-z0-9 ]/i))  
             count++;  
         else  
             {  
             alert('Invalid char '+mystring[i]);  
             return false;  
             }  
     }  
   if (count > 11 || count < 2){  
        alert('String length invalid');  
        return false;  
   }  
return true;  
}`

Comment: hey everybody that works great, but right now, it's displaying, a alert box, how do I incorporate that script, in a new jQuery.validator.addMethod so I can output it as maxlength ??

Comment: Hey Again, toni and ojovirtual, I wrote my code like this, and it Works great, thanks for the help.    
`jQuery.validator.addMethod("maxtext", function(value, element) {
     var count=0; for (var i in value) { 
        if (value[i].match(/[æøåÆØÅ]/)) count +=2; else if (value[i].match(/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/i)) count++; else {
            alert('empty fields and special, is not allowed '+value[i]); return false; 
        } 
    } if (count > 11 || count < 2){return false; } return true;
     },
     "recipients name is to long!"
 );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to do that:

```
var str = "A string with some strange characters like: æ ø å Æ Ø Å";
var total = str.length + (str.match(/æ|ø|Æ|Ø|Å/g)||[]).length;
```

> *`str.length = 55`*
>   **`total = 60`**

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode it first.

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

You can take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/vLmQ8/ to see it in action.

Please see http://monsur.hossa.in/2012/07/20/utf-8-in-javascript.html for more information.

Comment: This is the right way, as it will work even for characters not explicitly asked for. (Assuming that the encoding actually is UTF-8, but that sounds really likely.) For a complete answer, you should extend that code to actually compute the length of the result of encoding…